# Inequality with ratios of power functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> I want to prove that $$f(x,y,v,z)=\frac{v^{0.5}}{(-z)^{0.5}-(-v-z)^{0.5}}-\frac{x^{0.5}+y^{0.5}-(x+y+v+z)^{0.5}}{(-v-z)^{0.5}}\geq 0$$ with $x\geq y\geq v>0>z$ with $x+y+z<0$ and $x+y+v+z\geq0$.

I tried with KKT conditions, but did not reach useful results. I noticed, numerically, that I could set $x=y$ and $x+y+v+z=0$ and then discuss with $v,z$ variables, but I do not have a justification for this. Maybe it is a sequential optimization.

Comment: You may use $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \le \sqrt{2(x+y)}$ first.